# Currently writing but to realize my beginning was already overused

Tags: character-development, plot

I am halfway finished with my book and I did some little research to realize I overused one of the most common beginnings: The main character dying in the first chapter.

Is it fine to keep it like that? Because the main point was to have my character die first to keep my plot going.

Comment: Does the main character die in the first chapter? If so, I wouldn't regard that as very common.

Comment: @S.Mitchell:  The protagonist dying in the first chapter is not unusual.  There are many books and stories that start with the main character dying, with the rest of the story telling how the character came to the point and conditions that caused the death.  You know that the character will die - but the interesting thing is how they reach that point and why.  Find and read a copy of "The Key" by Isaac Asimov, as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every story has to start somewhere with the protagonist being in a state of complacency, then having that complacency broken.  How you decide to break that complacency is your first initial task as the author.  Even if it seems overdone, your plot will have to start *somewhere* to galvanize the protagonist into action.

If your story is the "Exploring the Land of the Dead" variety, consider this: will your story have any contextual difference if the protagonist suddenly has to flee their home to lands far away and can never return?  (This happened to Luke Skywalker in "A New Hope" after his Aunt and Uncle's farm was destroyed).  He didn't die but his complacency was broken and he could never return to life the same way.

So, I wouldn't say the protagonist dying is "overused"--it's simply a mechanism to get the plot moving, which is required by the narrative.